# Convert image to pdf a5 with not empty areas

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm using this command

```
mogrify -format pdf -page a5  iguana2.jpg
```

to convert a **jpg** file into a **pdf**. The problem is that the result has a white border. I'd like the image to full fill the a5 page (it's ok if borders of the image are lost).

Original image:

[image: original image]

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use IM, I suggest using LaTeX to realize this. The following tex code is an example.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\RequirePackage[margin=0in]{geometry} 
\RequirePackage{graphicx}       

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{example.jpg} # if the width > height
    \includegraphics[height=1.0\paperheight]{example.jpg} # if the height > width
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The code is very easy to understand. Use `latex` compile it.